# Debate about Free Will

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, free-will

I had this debate with someone about whether or not we have free will or are we determined and my argument was we are determined because of how we are constructed by nature basically we haven't chosen how we want to be nor how are brain is going to develop in later stages of life every idea that we develop, new ways of thinking new emotions are all because of how inherently our genes constructed us even later new ways of thinking.

I personally think if we fully understood how our genes and our brain develops and we had full awareness of how every region is brain is connected and make us think we will realize that there isn't any choices we do and its all predetermined.

Also I think we can only take have responsibility of our free will if we had full awareness of every neuron that fires in our brain and we could control each single one, hence descartes was wrong and religion is all bogus we are free from any responsibility.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what is your *definition* for free will. What freedom do you feel that you lack?

My definition for free will is the ability to decide our *actions*. We obviously do have that ability. We don't need any full control of all neurons. We only need to control our motor cortex neurons that control our muscles.

We cannot choose our preferences, needs or desires. The only choice we have is the choice of muscles, which ones to move in which order. We can and we must choose what we do to achieve our goals in the future.

Comment: I knew i would get this answer, basically you have to apply backwards reasoning and you have to look at what made you have the choice of doing this things you stated, think of what you can do as a human as a bunch of actions within a set, each of these actions you are able to preform were there because of a deterministic rule that you had no control of that put them there, free will ends when u have no awareness of your full identity or when your capacities do not go to infinity.

Comment: also you are being able to decide to do an action is not really you because you are already "constructed" If i can rebuild your brain on a computer and simulate a world like this i can predict with 100% certainty what action u was going to preform at any particular time

Comment: From that article: "This compatibilist free will should not be understood as some kind of ability to have chosen differently in an identical situation. A compatibilist can believe that a person can choose between many choices, but the choice is always determined by external factors.[15] If the compatibilist says "I may visit tomorrow, or I may not", he is saying that he does not know what he will choose—whether he will choose to follow the subconscious urge to go or not."

Comment: #Bardeen I'm sorry but I don't understand what you are trying to say. If I'm not choosing my own actions, then who is choosing them? Whose purposes am I serving, if not my own?

Comment: #Felicia I cannot see any logic in compatibilism. Who is actually making the choice, the compatibilist himself or the "external factors"? Who is this "external factors" guy anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Free will needs deterministic processes to exist in the first place. A physical process can be free only if the determined process is there in the first place. If the determined will can develop freely depends on the circumstances.

You write:

"I personally think if we fully understood how our genes and our brain develops and we had full awareness of how every region is brain is connected and make us think we will realize that there isn't any choices we do and its all predetermined."

So if we know how our genes and genes develop and how every region in the brain is connected and makes us think we realize that there are no free choices and that everything is predetermined?
Like I wrote, a determined process has to exist in the first place. This determined process will develop freely if there are no other free determined wills to limit your own free will.
You can't have full knowledge of the physical process you are, because knowledge of that state involves that same process. You could have knowledge of the physical process I am but would that make me less free? To obtain that knowledge you had to have access to all my elementary fields and how would you obtain that?
If a god outside the universe could obtain the knowledge of the positions in phase  space of all elementary particles he could not tell us. If hed we could act differently, and if that god should incorporate his communication in his knowledge then his knowledge would be incomplete because the knower is then part of that what the knowledge is about.
I know pretty well what my brain, my body, and the physical world is about. It's indeed a gigantic determined process with inherent determined will. That doesn't make it not free. On the contrary, it gives my will a means to evolve. There are lots of processes that impede our process in the world. The will can be made a slave to other wills. The will simply is. It can be free or imprisoned. But physical laws don't make it unfree.

Then you write:

"Also I think we can only take have responsibility of our free will if we had full awareness of every neuron that fires in our brain and we could control each single one, hence descartes was wrong and religion is all bogus we are free from any responsibility."

Full awareness of every neuron that fires? That's impossible, let alone controlling them. Knowledge of your brainstate is not an a condition for the will to be free. You can't have a full image of your own brain. Like explained. The researchers who predicted which finger people were about to raise knew that before those people did. Are those people not free because the researchers knew? Are you not free if I know each Tohu, Vohu, and gauge particley ou consist of, including the gauge fields between them, so I know your each and every state in time and your surrounding? No. This would not make you less free.

Comment: Alright so we seem to agree on the idea that determinism must be first in order for free will to exist. But we disagree on the will being free, you think that will is still free even if there is a deterministic process which made it be. I just don't get why do you still think there is still freedom that exists in you, if you are a finite discrete creature i can know all the possible actions that will come out of you, knowing the construction of your brain how the wiring of your brain is i can put in a simulation and your simulated clone will do everything exactly how u would in real life

Comment: My definition of free will is when i can never know what action im going to preform now and no other creature even god can tell me what im going to do because the possibilities of my actions are infinite, but that is impossible cause our world is discrete and we are finite

Comment: It doesn't make sense to me to call yourself free if anything you can do is known or can be predicted 100% certainty

Comment: @Bardeen I I know your complete particle state you still have a free will. Why not?

Comment: Knowledge of my brain state does give more freedom if i killed a person because Neuron X fired and i wasn't the one who manipulated my brain chemistry and manipulated the genes from the start why am i responsible for killing that person and also me not being able to stop my self from killing that person is because Neuron Y wasn't fully developed again it was not me who constructed my own brain FREE WILL JUST DOESN'T EXIST how can u not see it, you thinking u have a will for example typing is because a set of event that led you to type it that were not random how are you free then

Comment: @Bardeen I am my body and there are parallel ion currents on my neural network flowing.  Nobody forces these currents or the will inside them. It develops freely.

Comment: its not about it being forced it's about if you did action Y and you could go back and make the ion current do a different flow by then you will be free but since the flow of the ion led to your conscious act certain way you are not free because you didn't haven't infinite possibilities to manipulate the ion and god knew how the ion was going to flow @Felicia

Comment: @Bardeen Not sure I understand. Im not free because I didn't have infinite possibilities to manipulate the ion current? What if I had these infinite possibilities? How to choose?

Comment: you will choose randomly but it will be impossible to know the output because there is infinite amount and not even a god should know,  by then you are free because there was no constraint and you can't put uncontrollable constraints on infinity @Felicia

Comment: Please do not discuss in comments, the response could just link to https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compatibilism , where the concept of compatibility is explained well and in much detail.